# C++ call child method from parent reference

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I have an

```
    std::list<TYPE>
```

which may contain child classes of TYPE. I need to iterate over the list and call the child's overridden version of a function defined in TYPE but I won't know which subclass of TYPE I have and the reference is of type TYPE.

If I call using the TYPE reference it will call the TYPE's virtual method and not my subclass method. Is there a way to say "call the furthest subclass' overridden version of this method"?

Comment: Is the TYPE a typedef to a pointer or a reference (to an actual type)?

Comment: I would take another look at your design.

Comment: it will call the TYPE's virtual method and not my subclass method ... you make a mistake with your virtual functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store references in a `std::list` and your list doesn't contain instances of a subclass of `TYPE`.

If you assign an instance of a subclass of `TYPE` to a `TYPE`, it gets "sliced", which means that all subclass information is lost. This is why the `TYPE` method is called - the object *is* a `TYPE`, not a subclass of `TYPE`.

If you want polymorphism you must store pointers - `TYPE*` or a smart pointer - in the list.

Answer (score 0):

No, since there may be various child classes inherited from your base class and you won't be sure what method to call. However, you can use static_cast to convert your base class reference to the child class reference.